# Are complex split-octonions isomorphic to a more easily-defined algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, octonions, sedenions

I write fiction and nonfiction, both which are mathy.  My fiction is not usually supermathy but I'm working on a fictional story that has some math in it, and I prefer accuracy to mathbabble.  I'm stepping outside my particular math domain so what I am asking may be incredibly naive, but here it is.

I have two questions.

$0)$ Are complex split-octonions (that is, split-octonions with complex coefficients) isomorphic to another algebra more easily defined or described?  I mention this because the Muses's so-called "conic sedenions" are isomorphic to complex octonions, and for all I know complex split-octonions can be reduced to some other algebra.

$1)$ Can complex split-octonions be represented as a simple subalgebra (I am using this word very loosely, obv.) of trigintaduonions?  If not, could they be represented as a simple subalgebra of a higher Cayley construction?

Thanks for your time, and if this question is ludicrous in some way, let me know so I can fix or remove it.